# XPath Select the uppermost nodes that contains just one childless node

Tags: .net, xpath, count

I'm looking for a XPath in .NET that selects just the **uppermost nodes** that contains **just one** terminal (childless) node

```
A <--
    B
        C
D
    E <--
        F
    G <--
    H <--
        I 
            J


C, F, G, J are terminal
```

I want to get rid of useless nested items and promote terminals if possible:

```
C to A position; F to E position; G remains in place; ...
```

## Edit

I think I'm getting close with

```
.//*[count(descendant-or-self::terminal)=1] [ not(ancestor::*[count(.//terminal)=1]) ]
```

where terminal can be selected by

```
*[not(*)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own solution:

```
.//*[count(descendant-or-self::terminal)=1] [ not(ancestor::*[count(descendant::terminal)=1]) ]
```

where `terminal = *[not(*)]`

With the first condition `[count(descendant-or-self::terminal)=1]` we select `<--` items. With the second condition    `[ not(ancestor::*[count(descendant::terminal)=1]) ]` we select `<···` items:

```
A             <--    <···     A
    B         <--
        C     <--
D                    <···
    E         <--    <···        E
        F     <--
    G         <--    <···        G
    H         <--    <···        H
        I     <--
            J <--
```

Intersection is { A E G H } as wanted

The best way to achieve promotion of terminal items and removal of one-child parents is by means of a recursive method:

```
Public Sub XmlTrimOneChildParents(ByRef xE As XmlElement)
    Dim xNodeList As XmlNodeList = xE.SelectNodes("./*")
    Select Case xNodeList.Count
        Case 0 'terminal
        Case 1 'Remove And Promote Child
            Dim xChild As XmlNode = xNodeList(0)
            XmlTrimOneChildParents(xChild)
            xE.ParentNode.InsertBefore(xChild, xE)
            xE.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xE)
        Case else
            For Each xChild As XmlNode In xNodeList
                XmlTrimOneChildParents(xChild)
            Next
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just `//*[count(descendant-or-self::*)=1]` ?

```
% cat uppermost.xml 
<R>
  <A><B><C/></B></A>
  <D>
    <E><F/></E>
    <G/>
    <H><I><J/></I></H>
  </D>
</R>
% xpquery '//*[count(descendant-or-self::*)=1]' uppermost.xml
<C/>
<F/>
<G/>
<J/>
%
```

Comment: It looks like you're obtaining childless nodes. I want to select {A E G H}, something like the first grandparent whose descendants are all one-child. I want to point where the one-child policy began.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see an easy way to do that without recursion (is the node moving up 1, or 2 (or more?) steps?); probably easier to select the childless nodes and then to use other code to walk them up the `parent` axis until the other-nodes (or root element) condition is met.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The easiest way seems to move up those childless nodes by means of a recursive method. However I was more intrigued and I was experiencing more trouble thinking about the XPath expression.